# Why are my vertices being mirrored and how do I fix it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

Bear in mind, I am quite new to blender.

I've run into a problem. I'm trying to model a head and I'm creating the vertices and faces, but when I move some vertices another one snaps to a completely unrelated position.
Here are some images highlighting the problem:

[image]

[image]

All I did in there was move the selected point a little bit back along the y axis.

Do any of you know why this is happening and how to fix it? I really need help on this.

Comment: Transformation orientation, modifiers or snapping could be the problem here or something else, a bit difficult to say going on images alone. Can you share the blend file at the time of posting this.

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on? Shrinkwrap or Mirror could cause it.

Comment: iKlsR: I'm not entirely sure where to upload that, does this site have a dedicated file sharing system? Or maybe a preferred third party?

CharlesL: Nope, no modifiers. I thought it was mirror doing it, but when I removed it there was no change.

Comment: @CustardCrusader just use a file sharing service. Dropbox etc. Also, do you by any chance have snapping enabled? Look in the bottom header for a little magnet icon. Is it red?

Comment: iKlsR: No, snapping's off, tried that too. Here's the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/haxj89bht5f0rkp/face%20with%20reference%20glitch.blend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *X Mirror* enabled. Open the toolself with <kbd>T</kbd> and untick it, it's under *Mesh Options*. What this does is that it will try to mimic whatever you are doing on one side of your mesh on the other.

[image]

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Basics/Mirror).

> The X-mirror option of the Mesh Options panel allows you edit both “sides” of your mesh in a single action. When you transform an element (vertex, edge or face), if there is its exact X-mirrored counterpart (in local space), it will be transformed accordingly, through a symmetry along the local X axis.

This didn't affect the mouth area of your model as only half of it was modeled while you had a *complete* eye ring.

Comment: Seems like such an insubstantial thing... Thank you so much, this place seems to have a great community.